# Find and subset patterns in data table

Tags: r, data.table

Suppose that we have a data table with missing values (see example below).

```
library(data.table)
mat <- matrix(rnorm(50), ncol = 5)
mat[c(1,3,5,9,10,11,14,37,38)] <- NA

DT <- as.data.table(mat)
```

In total, we have 5 unique missing data patterns in our example (see `unique(!is.na(DT))`).

Suppose now further that we would like to find these patterns and identify them according to their frequency of occurrence (starting with the most frequent pattern indicated by 1).

```
DTna <- as.data.table(!is.na(DT))
DTna <- DTna[, n := .N, by = names(x = DTna)]
DTna <- DTna[, id := 1:nrow(x = DTna)]
DTna <- DTna[order(n, decreasing = TRUE)]
DTna <- DTna[, m := .GRP, by = eval(names(x = DT))]
```

Finally, observations with a particular pattern should be subsetted according to a prespecification (here e.g. 1 for the most frequent pattern).

```
pattern <- 1
i <- DTna[m == pattern, id]
DT[i]
```

In summary, I need to find observations which share the same missing data pattern and subsequently subset them according to a prespecification (e.g. the most frequent pattern). Please note that I need to subset `DT` instead of `DTna`.

**Question**

So far, the above code works as expected, but is there a more elegant way using data.table?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would add a grouping column to DT to join and filter on:

```
DT[, nag := do.call(paste0, lapply(.SD, function(x) +is.na(x)))]
nagDT = DT[, .N, by=nag][order(-N), nagid := .I][, setorder(.SD, nagid)]

#      nag N nagid
# 1: 10000 4     1
# 2: 00000 2     2
# 3: 00010 2     3
# 4: 11000 1     4
# 5: 01000 1     5

# subsetting
my_id = 1L
DT[nagDT[nagid == my_id, nag], on=.(nag), nomatch=0]
```

which gives

```
   V1         V2         V3          V4         V5   nag
1: NA  1.3306093 -2.1030978  0.06115726 -0.2527502 10000
2: NA  0.2852518 -0.1894425  0.86698633 -0.2099998 10000
3: NA -0.1325032 -0.5201166 -0.94392417  0.6515976 10000
4: NA  0.3199076 -1.0152518 -1.61417902 -0.6458374 10000
```

If you want to omit the new column in the result:

```
DT[nagDT[nagid == my_id, nag], on=.(nag), nomatch=0, !"nag"]
```

And to also omit the blank columns:

```
DT[nagDT[nagid == my_id, nag], on=.(nag), nomatch=0, !"nag"][, 
  Filter(function(x) !anyNA(x), .SD)]
```

Comment: Great! How would you adjust your last command line in order to remove also columns with missing values (e.g. remove "V1" and "nag" in your example above)?

Comment: @jakob Good question. I've edited in one way to do it above.

Comment: Excellent. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2):

An alternative, which is undoubtedly inferior (but nonetheless provided for variety), is

```
DT[, patCnt := setDT(stack(transpose(DT)))[,
   paste(+(is.na(values)), collapse=""), by="ind"][,
   patCnt := .N, by=(V1)]$patCnt]
```

which returns

```
DT
            V1          V2         V3         V4          V5 patCnt
 1:         NA          NA -1.5062011 -0.9846015  0.12153714      1
 2:  1.4176784 -0.08078952 -0.8101335  0.6437340 -0.49474613      2
 3:         NA -0.08410076 -1.1709337 -0.9182901  0.67985806      4
 4:  0.2104999          NA -0.1458075  0.8192693  0.05217464      1
 5:         NA -0.73361504  2.1431392 -1.0041705  0.29198857      4
 6:  0.3841267 -0.75943774  0.6931461 -1.3417511 -1.53291515      2
 7: -0.8011166  0.26857593  1.1249757         NA -0.57850361      2
 8: -1.5518674  0.52004986  1.6505470         NA -0.34061924      2
 9:         NA  0.83135928  0.9155882  0.1856450  0.31346976      4
10:         NA  0.60328545  1.3042894 -0.5835755 -0.17132227      4
```

Then subset

```
DT[patCnt == max(patCnt)]
   V1          V2         V3         V4         V5 patCnt
1: NA -0.08410076 -1.1709337 -0.9182901  0.6798581      4
2: NA -0.73361504  2.1431392 -1.0041705  0.2919886      4
3: NA  0.83135928  0.9155882  0.1856450  0.3134698      4
4: NA  0.60328545  1.3042894 -0.5835755 -0.1713223      4
```